# Automatically increment build number with Gradle (not Android)

Tags: gradle

How to automatically increment build number with Gradle?

Build number should be stored in file and be under version control.

Comment: How about this approach: http://devdeeds.com/auto-increment-build-number-using-gradle-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was searching for Gradle release plugin.

**Surprisingly many modern release plugins don't store the version directly in file, but rather determine it from VCS tags.**

So it's up to you which release plugin you will use:

- [ResearchGate Gradle release plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) (similar to Maven release plugin)
- [Ajobestar Gradle git release plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) (determines version form VCS tags)